# Databinding does not contain a property with the name

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, data-binding

I know this question has been asked numerous times before, but I feel the way I am going about this is a little unique so would like to get some more experienced feedback as this is baffling me a little bit.

As it stands, I have a basic ecom system, where clients can add there own products. When they edit the item, I have a section of dropdowns and would like the data to relate to the selections they made initially (to avoid them cocking up mass amounts of data!).

Currently 2 of the 3 drop downs work fine but the 3rd consists on data linked between 2 tables. This is where my problems are starting to occur. I can write to the table fine, but when I call data to the drop down I get the age old "does not contain a property with the name 'SubCatID'" error!!!

Here is the drop down code:

```
<li ID="ERow6" runat="server" visible="false"><label>Subcategory</label><span>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Subcategory" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("GetSubcat")%>' DataValueField="id" DataTextField="txt" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("SubCatID")%>'></asp:DropDownList></span></li>
```

and here is the c# I am calling:

```
GetSubcat = x.DT_Category.DT_SubCategories.Select(i => new { txt = i.SubcatName, id = i.SubCatID}),
```

How is it that the ID cannot be found????

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this line:

```
i => new { txt = i.SubcatName, id = i.SubCatID}),
```

You are creating a new anonymous object with properties `txt` and `id` and it looks like you're binding to `SubCatID`, correct me if I'm wrong.